# How to safely swap values of two objects in array in one request?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm storing the order of items in a specific context and want to allow changing the order of the items.

Example document:

```
{
 _id: docID,
 items: [
     {
         _id: 1,
         orderNr: 0,
     },
     {
         _id: 2,
         orderNr: 1,
     },
     {
         _id: 3,
         orderNr: 2,
     },
 ]
}
```

**Solutions I could think of:**

The 'brute' way to do this would be to find the document, change the array with JavaScript and use $set to swap the entire array. This seems unsafe.

The other way I thought of was using arrayFilters and using data from the client. This seems safe, since the array filters require that each item still has its old orderNr value, however it requires knowing the current orderNr. Example:

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: new ObjectID(item1Data.contextID), "items._id": new ObjectID(item1Data._id) },
        {
          $set: {
            "items.$[item1].orderNr": item2Data.orderNr,
            "items.$[item2].orderNr": item1Data.orderNr,
          },
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [
            { "item1._id": item1Data._id, "item1.orderNr": item1Data.orderNr },
            { "item2._id": item2Data._id, "item2.orderNr": item2Data.orderNr },
          ],
        }
      );
```

Is there a way I could just use the ID of both items to swap their `orderNr` values, without having to know the *current* `orderNr` from the client or from an extra request — using existing values straight from the document, during the request and just using ID to swap?

Comment: What is your goal? ... to swap elements of the array based only on array indexes?

Comment: Probably swapping elements in the array themselves wouldn't be necessary and might need $pull and $push. So goal is to swap the orderNr field's value based only on the IDs of two elements in the safest way.

Although come to think about it, it might actually be safest to use both the ID and current orderNr, since using only ID to swap positions wouldn't ensure they weren't already swapped! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you want to be using the [aggregation pipeline updates framework](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), this will allow you to use aggregation expressions within your update body.

At this point you can achieve this update in multiple different ways, here is one way which I think is the most "readable". Essentially we iterate over all items using `$map`, and if the documents match based on the id we convert them:

```
const item1Data = { _id: 1 };
const item2Data = { _id: 3};

db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      item1: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$items",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  item1Data._id
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      item2: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$items",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this._id",
                  item2Data._id
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: "$items",
          in: {
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this._id",
                      item1Data._id
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        orderNr: "$item2.orderNr"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this._id",
                      item2Data._id
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$this",
                      {
                        orderNr: "$item1.orderNr"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$this"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: [
      "item1",
      "item2"
    ]
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6esU-USawVD)

Comment: Ah, incredible! Thank you for providing this extensive solution and also a demo! I'll definitely read up more on how this works.